# Rails Controller Triggering Both Branches Of If-Else Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new here so I hope it's appropriate for new accounts to ask questions straight away. I've been working with Rails for sometime now and usually I'm pretty good at researching and solving my own problems - but this one has had me stumped for a few days now.

I have a create action being called in a controller that contains an if-else statement that is conditional based on a check_box post parameter. I can see that the parameter is being posted to the controller so the statement should be able to correctly branch but something strange is happening. The controller executes both branches of the statement, but because my parameters are trimmed depending on that check_box, the second branch always errors out. I'm fairly confident this has little to do with routes.

Please see my code below:

Controller:

```
  def create
@quote = Quote.find(params[:quote_id])

if params[:quote_item][:custom] == 1
  @quote_item = @quote.quote_items.new(quote_item_params)
  @quote_item.rate = nil
  @quote_item.custom = true
  @quote_item.unit_price = params[:quote_item][:unit_price]
  @quote_item.rate_name = params[:quote_item][:title]
else
  @quote_item = @quote.quote_items.new(quote_item_params)
  @quote_item.custom = false
  @rate = Rate.find(params[:quote_item][:rate_id])
    @quote_item.unit_price = @rate.price
  @quote_item.rate_name = @rate.product.name
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @quote.save
    format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote item was successfully added.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @quote }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to @quote }
    format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

View:

```
    <% if @rates.any? %>
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@quote, @quote_item], layout: :inline) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'input-sm', hide_label: true, :placeholder => "Line Title" %>
  <%= f.select(:rate_id, @rates.collect {|r| [r.select_summary_text, r.id ] }, { hide_label: true }, { :class => 'input-sm' }) %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'input-sm', hide_label: true, :min => 1, :length => 2,  :value => 1 %>
  <%= f.text_field :unit_price, class: 'input-sm', hide_label: true, :min => 1, :length => 2, :prepend => "$" %>
    <%= f.text_field :note, class: 'input-sm', hide_label: true, :placeholder => "Note (Optional)" %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Quote Item", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %>
  <%= f.check_box :custom, label: "Override" %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<div class="well well-sm"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> No pricing for this customer has been set. Set product pricing for this jobs customer <%= link_to user_path(@quote.job.user) do %>here.<% end %></div>
<% end %>
```

My create method errors out here:

```
@rate = Rate.find(params[:quote_item][:rate_id])
```

With:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Rate with 'id'=):
```

app/controllers/quote_items_controller.rb:19:in `create'

This error is correct though, because the rate ID isn't processed in first branch of the if-else statement. I've tried different check_box form fields, directly overriding 'custom' and both branches still run.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params hash contains strings.

Try swapping:

```
if params[:quote_item][:custom] == '1'
```

for your original:

```
if params[:quote_item][:custom] == 1
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I mark your answer as the correct one? Also, do you know why Rails processes both branches of the if-else statement rather than none when it doesn't recognize the string? Is this a fail-safe thing?

Comment: @JamesHeath click the green checkmark to the left of the answer

Comment: To the left of the answer are upvote/downvote arrows and a greyed out checkmark symbol. Click the checkmark by the corresponding answer in order to select the answer as the correct answer. As for the answer to the second question, In Ruby, only `true` and `false` are booleans, but everything else (expressions as well as objects) have "truthy" or "falsey" values. There's a good discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362). I'm not that experienced in Ruby myself, so I'll defer to people who have greater knowledge.